# Can I add a default category to images?

Tags: image, categories, safecracker-file

In channels you can define a default category to added entries, and I'd like to do something similar for added images.

This is a Safecracker File field (using Safecracker to upload).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is such a feature for assigning a default category to updated image from channel entry. Although, a category can be assigned to image in File Manager while editing it.

Your need can be fulfilled by developing an extension using the hook "entry_submission_end" which will assign a default category to uploaded image.